# iOS - How to get device names sortening in system address book?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, abaddressbook, cncontactstore

I would like to get which settings has user set in his device to set the same in my app. User can set "Sort Order" and "Display Order" as "First, Last" or "Last, First". Where can I access what user has set?

I found that in `ABAddressBook` class there is method [`defaultNameOrdering()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/abaddressbook/1458447-defaultnameordering?changes=la_5&language=objc) which looks like what I am looking for. But that class is deprecated. Is there a property or a same method in `CNContactStore`? And for both? Sort and display order?

I can't find any similar info in `CNContactStore`. Thanks for help

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactformatter/1397731-nameorderforcontact?language=objc

Comment: @MarekH Looks like partly what I am looking for. Not sure why it gets `CNContact` as parameter. But it's just for "Display order". Is there a way how to find out "Sort Order"?